# Gradle how to run the build. gradle

Tags: android, gradle, groovy, build.gradle

In groovy，

hello.groovy

```
println "Hello World"
```

We can get get the source code as following,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJb5W.png)

You can get the above code by Ctrl + T in GroovyConsole

So for build.gradle ,

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.emnets.luoly.thirdtest"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
}
```

Can someone tell me how to get similar code.

For a Java or c program, their entrance is main . So I want to konw what is entrance for build.gradle file,in other words, from where it began to run.Due to gradle is written by groovy code, and groovy is actually translated into the Java binary code for execution. I want to know execution entry of build gradle?
Someone can give me some advice ?

Comment: Can you have another go at explaining what you mean?

Comment: For a Java or c program, their entrance is  **main** . So I want to konw what is entrance  for  build.gradle file,in other words, from where it began to run.Due to gradle is written by groovy code, and groovy is actually translated into the Java binary code for execution.
I want to know  execution entry of build gradle?

Comment: Groovy is used as a DSL, and gradle uses it to define your build. Build.gradle isn't executed as if it were a standard program, it's used to describe what gradle does

Comment: I know you mean.
But I like to understand what is  gradle operation mechanism.On the basis of the build.gradle ，it finishs the work step by step

Comment: No, it builds an internal model of requirements, then decided how to best proceed

Comment: Can you provide me some electronic data or url that may be help me to understand?  Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you seen http://igorpopov.io/2014/05/01/understanding-gradle/

Comment: Thank you for providing a url.It helps me well.